# How do I stop and start nodes Amazon EC2 Instances at scheduled intervals time

Tags: amazon-web-services, scheduled-tasks, startup

I want to start and stop nodes on Amazon EC2 instance on certain time. How can I do it?

Comment: Programatically? Or via configuring your instance? If it's just a configuration question, then it's off-topic for stackoverlow. If you're trying to do it programmatically, tell us what you've tried so far and what it does (or doesn't do).

Comment: Googled and found this in less than 5 seconds: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/stop-start-ec2-instances/ and this too: https://schen1628.wordpress.com/2014/02/04/auto-start-and-stop-your-ec2-instances/ This is way to broad a question with no details/info about what you're trying to do and what you've done

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options for it:

You can use some simple lambda functions that can describe your EC2 instances and start or stop instances, and then use them on a schedule: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html

You can use auto scaling to add or remove instances in an auto scaling group, including moving from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 0. This can also be scheduled: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/schedule_time.html

You can also using CloudWatch alarms to control your EC2 instances. You can do that on various metrics, such as being idle at night, if you want to make sure that your EC2 instances are not wasted when not needed: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingAlarmActions.html

And you can combine the various options together, when some are stoping your instances and some are starting them back.